# Contact point for Play Framework?

Tags: playframework

Who is/are the best contact points for Play Framework? Can we have email addresses?
Even something like contact@playframework.org if individuals don't want to give their email address.

There is the fourm, but it's becoming noisy, and sometimes it's better to have a few people to contact directly about specific issues/questions.

(I don't mean to spam them with trivial/frequent problems, just to send one email a.t.m)

**Edit** - Please don't post any contact information that isn't already public knowledge, without the consent of that person!

Comment: Downvoted because I felt this wasn't an appropriate question for SO. It also opens the door for people to post personal contact info for others without their consent.

Comment: @MarkS - I believe it is on topic. It is a question about a programming framework. Can you point me to a FAQ or other entry that this question is against?

Comment: Technically you are correct that it is a question about a programming framework. However, subjectively, it "feels" wrong. You are not asking a technical question, you are asking for contact info to be provided publicly without regard to the consent of the owner of the contact info. You claim that you "don't mean to spam". However, you are asking the info to be publicized and available to other spammers, which is disrespectful to the people you seek, in my opinion.

Comment: @MarkS - the info is there already. I'm looking to aggregate publicly known information. I'll edit to make this clear.

Comment: that's much better :). Thanks. Down vote gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several solutions are available

- **[Public]** Twitter: [@playframework](https://twitter.com/playframework)
- **[More private]** Through GitHub profile

  - The list of *playframework* contributors is available **[here](https://github.com/playframework/play/contributors)**
  - Display their profile (for instance, top contributor is **[guillaumebort](https://github.com/guillaumebort))**. Some of them publicly list their email address (Guillaume Bort does :) )

[image]

- Hit the **"Message"** button to contect those who do not advertize their email address

[image: Message button]

Comment: Alright, I'll try messaging Guillaume directly - thanks.

I don't like Twitter as a direct communication medium, I prefer good old email.